# Convert boolean expression to only have positive literals

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I'd like to do quite a specialised conversion of a boolean expression in Python. Basically, I want my expression to only contain positive literals, for example:

Instead of:

```
AND(~A, B, ~C, D)
```

I would want:

```
AND(B, D, NOR(A, C))
```

Any ideas how I could accomplish this? I've tried playing with Python EDA, but to no avail.

The use case for this is that I would like to simplify a complex boolean expression before I put it into a database.

**EDIT 1:**

Came up with my own not very elegant solution:

Use PyEDA to form an expression from the input, PyEDA simplifies it automatically using just AND, OR and NOT.

```
If AND(Not(A), Not(B) ...):
    Change to NOR(A, B ...)
If OR(Not(A), Not(B) ...):
    Change to NAND(A, B ...)
IF AND(Not(A), B ...):
    Change to AND(B, NOR(A ...))
IF OR(Not(A), B ...):
    Change to OR(B, NAND(A ...))
```

And you get the general idea. As I said, bit long-winded but it was the best solution I could come up with for this. I wrote the above from memory so please tell me if I got it wrong! Also, My database handles an AND/OR etc. with a single literal in it, so that's not an issue.

Comment: Why don't you want NOT?  Why is NAND ok but NOT is not?

Comment: NAND(A, C) is not equivalent to AND(~A, ~C).

Comment: In other words, you want only positive literals, with all negations being applied to more complex terms?

Comment: Also, I hope you're aware that this might not make things any simpler. The most straightforward way to do it (replacing ~X with NAND(X, X)) certainly doesn't.

Comment: It's because it makes my database design simpler. I'm using django-treebeard in Python, so I have a Conditional node that can be AND, OR etc., then from each Conditional node I have a many-to-many field to the model represented by the variables in the example above.

Comment: @user2357112 - Yes, I got the example wrong, but you get the general idea, I'll try and fix it.

Comment: @delnan - Yes! That's a much better way to describe it, I'll modify the description above.

Comment: You should look into normal forms; if you can accept a common one, for example [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) you will likely find a good algorithm for conversion.

Comment: Would `AND(NAND(A, A), B, NAND(C, C), D)` be a workable solution?

Comment: Well, while I'm traversing an AND block, I could add all the negative ones into a NOR child in the database, then if I'm traversing an OR block, I could add all the negative ones into a NAND child. I may bite the bullet and do this, it might not be in its most simplified form, but it would work. @poke, I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I will read up on CNF.

Comment: I did pretty much what I said in the comment above, it's not very elegant and it's quite long-winded. I feel like there must be a much neater / clever solution out there, but it's above me. It does the job and I wrote loads of unit tests to make sure what was going in was the same as what was going out! I'm using Python EDA before passing the data in, it does some simplification itself before I do my own AND/OR/NAND/NOR modifications on top.